# ios8 like Vibrancy effect on Android

Tags: android, ios8, android-edittext, android-canvas, porter-duff

Has anyone tried the ios 8 like vibrancy effect to EditText and Bitmaps on Android?

https://github.com/ide/UIVisualEffects/blob/master/Screenshots/UIVisualEffects.png

PorterDuffXferMode looks like the way forward but I will be interested in knowing if anyone has actually tried this for different widgets like EditText, TextView, ImageView and Lists on Android? I am specifically referring to see through text visible through layers of background and blurred overlays. Also interested to know if anyone has been bold enough to roll out Android libraries already for this?

Comment: For e.g. see the example screen grab on on https://github.com/ide/UIVisualEffects. I know lot of this can be achieved by using PorterduffXfermode but i am really checking if there are any ready libraries around getting this effect at an activity or fragment level. i.e. the effect is applied to each view in activity (e.g. edittext, imageview etc)

Comment: I would also like to get a general view from developers around the performance implications of achieving this effect at an app level.